# How to find GTK installed by vcpkg in CMake

Tags: windows, cmake, gtk, gtk3, vcpkg

I install the GTK packages with:

```
vcpkg install gtk:x64-windows
```

I also set the environment variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to `C:\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake`， but `find_package` can't find GTK. How do I find GTK in CMake?

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure to run `.\vcpkg integrate install` via Powershell-Admin after you have built GTK? Are you building your project with the `x64-windows` triplet defined (**VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET**)?

^ Once you do that, delete *CMakeCache*, and/or test regeneration to another folder and try Configuring again.

On the CMake side, check that your *CMakeLists* has `find_package (GTK)` somewhere in there as well. You'll probably also have to define `GTK_INCLUDE_DIR` and link GTK via `target_link_libraries` on the CMake side.

Answer (score 0):

CMAKE find_package along with vcpkg integration doesn't work as intended, at least with GTK4 libraries. I am able to fix by adding the dependencies manually something like below or probably create a CMAKE macro

```
include_directories(${PATH TO VCPKG INSTALLED}/gtk-4.0)
include_directories(${PATH TO VCPKG INSTALLED}/gtkmm-4.0) .. include rest of the used dependencies
```

The above should be able to compile the code, the following libraries should also be linked as below.

`target_link_libraries(main "[VCPKG Intallation]/lib/sigc-3.0.lib") and all dependencies gtkmm-4.0.lib, gtk-4.lib .. as per your needs`

Comment: You answer is totally not readable. Please edit it and use markdown code embedding function.